# Change background-color of dynamically generated elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following use case, which generates `<li>` and `<tr>` dynamically (varying number):

[image]

If I hover `<li>` **Point 1** on the `timeline`, I want to change the `background-color` of `<tr>` containing the text **"Point 1     $2.90"**
in the `table` on the right:

**Timeline**

```
<!-- start timeline -->
<ol class="timeline">
  <li class="timeline dot">
    Point 1
  </li>
  <li class="timeline dot">
    Point 2
  </li>
  <li class="timeline dot">
    Point 3
  </li>
</ol>
<!-- end timeline -->
```

**Table:**

```
<!-- start table -->
<table class="mdl-data-table services" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="mdl-data-table__cell">Beschreibung</th>
      <th>Preis</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell">Point 1</td>
      <td>$2.90</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell">Point 2</td>
      <td>$1.25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell">Point 3</td>
      <td>$2.35</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<!-- end table -->
```

How can I implement this using jQuery? It should be a generic approach, because the `<li>` and `<tr>` elements must be generated dynamically.

Is it useful to append a data-attribute in order to differentiate the elements?

Comment: some sort of data attribute connecting the two would not be a bad idea.

Comment: are the generations of the `<tr>` and the `<li>` one to one in that for each `<tr>` there will be its corresponding `<li>`. and would they be in the same order (farthest left `<li>` corresponding with the top most `<tr>`?

Comment: @indubitablee yes that is what I intend

Comment: @j08691 not very much yet. I am not sure how to implement it :-/ I will access a REST endpoint to get an array of elements. Then I will iterate through this array of elements and generate the HTML output as shown above. There I can add the dynamically generated data-attribute as suggested above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this could get you started.

`$(this)` refers to the hovered element

`.index()` is used to find the index of the hovered element

the selectors are general and are aware of dynamically added elements to the DOM, and `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` tend to be less finicky than `.hover()` (sometimes in chrome if you hover in and out of an element really fast, it'll "spazz out" is as best as i can describe it)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('ol.timeline').on('mouseenter', 'li.timeline.dot', function() {
     var index = $(this).index() + 1;
        $('table.mdl-data-table.services tbody tr:nth-child(' + index + ')').css('background-color', 'gray');
    }).on('mouseleave', 'li.timeline.dot', function() {
     var index = $(this).index() + 1;
        $('table.mdl-data-table.services tbody tr:nth-child(' + index + ')').css('background-color', '');
    });
});
```

```css
ol {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}
table {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="timeline">
  <li class="timeline dot">
    Point 1
  </li>
  <li class="timeline dot">
    Point 2
  </li>
  <li class="timeline dot">
    Point 3
  </li>
</ol>
<table class="mdl-data-table services">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="mdl-data-table__cell">Beschreibung</th>
      <th>Preis</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell">Point 1</td>
      <td>$2.90</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell">Point 2</td>
      <td>$1.25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell">Point 3</td>
      <td>$2.35</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you looking for something like this:

This **would only work** if you have only **one class named `timeline` and `services`**. If there are more than one, there would be conflicts and will not work.

So in that case give **unique `class` or `id`** to both of these and try then.

**<kbd>[Working : Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/n753tw3f/1/)</kbd>**

**CSS**

```
.addBackground
{
    background:#333;
    color:#ccc;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$("ol.timeline li").hover(
    function(event){
        var curHover = $(this).index();
        curHover = curHover + 1;
        $(".services tbody tr:nth-child(" + curHover + ")").addClass("addBg");

    },function() {
     $(".services tbody tr").removeClass("addBackground");
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried the code below, but something along these lines should work.

```
$('li.timeline').on("hover", function () {
    var index = $('ol.timeline li').index($(this)),
        correspondingTr = $('.mdl-data-table td.mdl-data-table__cell')[index];

    correspondingTr.css('background-color', 'black');
});
```

What we're doing here is getting the position of the list item and using it to get the corresponding tr. The tr is then set to black.

I would also suggest adding some classes to make the selection easier.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your need, this should most likely work

```
$(li.timeline.dot).hover(function(index){
     $(tbody .mdl-data-table__cell)[index].css({"backgroundColor":"#cc00cc"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".timeline li").each(function(){
    $this = $(this);

    $this.mouseover(function(){
        $("table.services tr:eq("+($(this).index() + 1)+")").css('background','red');
    });

    $this.mouseout(function(){
        $("table.services tr:eq("+($(this).index() + 1)+")").css('background','transparent');
    });

});
```